# Routing new website to old DNS with Route 53, while persisting location of existing API

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

**The Problem**
We have a new website, hosted with Webflow. We need this website to be pointed to our old DNS (test.co). Unfortunately, this involves pointing our domain (test.co) to the Webflow DNS servers. This removes our API - hosted with EC2/Elastic Beanstalk - from the domain (test.co/api). We have a couple solutions - our main one is to move the Webflow files to our EC2 instance, but we can't do that yet. Our secondary one is to move our api to api.test.co. This works, but it breaks legacy iOS and Android apps that still use test.co/api.

We tried to use a redirect via Webflow, which I'm certain is simply a 301, to point to the EC2 instance (now located at api.test.co). But API calls don't go through this process (except GET). They get stopped at the redirect.

How can I point the new website to test.co, and yet also point test.co/api to the EC2 instance with our API on it, while maintaining the function of an API call to test.co/api?

Thanks so much to anybody contributing - will accept the first sensible answer that works!

Comment: Probably gonna need a proxy server if different paths go to different places.

Answer (score 0):

Will you app handle redirects, my first thought if you have to move the domain to point to another web endpoint is..:

Setup a new domain on the existing test.co/api example test1.co/api
Setup redirect on new web site for test.co/api redirect to test/api

or

Setup a new domain on the existing test.co/api example test1.co/api
Proxy API requests on new website /test.co/api to test1.co/api